# Remove spaces from multi select checkbox in mail body

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x, powermail

I have a powermail form in which I use a select box with multi selection.
In the email body the selected values are written as a comma separated list but with a space after each comma.

The developer of powermail (powermail 7.4.2 / TYPO3 9.5) has given me an answer on github: https://github.com/einpraegsam/powermail/issues/680

He directed me to an hardcoded entry in the answer.php of powermail.

I've changes the line in the answer.php to my needs but the spaces in the e-mail remain.

Can anyone give me a tip how to remove these spaces in the mail body for the multi select value list?

Comment: Maybe, it's a dirty way, but you could search & replace it within the variable. For example via https://viewhelpers.fluidtypo3.org/fluidtypo3/vhs/5.0.1/Format/PregReplace.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First question after code changes:
have you cleared all caches?

Then you need to verify that this line of code is responsible for your spaces. change the default delimiter to something new (like: `'#'`).
Differentiate between the default value of this function and the value which is transmitted when the function is called. You could change the default value, but if the function is called with the old value it will override the changed default.

If that doesn't help you need to debug where your values got concatenated. That could be in FLUID, Typoscript or PHP.

Comment: Hello Bernd,
thank you very much. 
The promlem was in another php file, wich I found with your reommended method to change the delimiter for a testrun.

If someone ever will have the same issue it's line 345 in powermail\Classes\Domain\Repository\MailRepository.php in powermail version 7.4.2